# "inform" as an intransitive verb?

Tags: transitivity, idiomatic-language

1. > He just wants to inform.
2. > I am just informing.
3. > She sometimes informs wrongly.

"Inform" is a *transitive* verb. ([Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inform)) But in the above sentences "inform" is used as an *intransitive* verb. Is such usages idiomatic?

Comment: This is common in Indian English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**inform**" can be used without a direct object in "*elliptical*" sentences where words are left out because they are understood from context *(the object of "inform" is meant to be understood by the reader)*.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inform) says "**inform**" is intransitive only in Am.E. and means "*to give information; to give information laying blame or accusation upon another*".

As for the grammar, your 1st sentence is incorrect, because *(the verb and subject in it don't agree - **corrected**)* there is no object of inform (since there is no context we can't tell who or what is being informed). Your second and third sentences are missing a direct object too.

Comment: So, can "he just intends to inform." be seen as an elliptical sentence?

Comment: In a context, yes.